When to use event() vs. eventFilter()
I'm confused about when you can use event() vs. eventFilter() to modify a widget's behaviour.
Two examples:
A Pushbutton where you can disable tooltips without changing the tooltip text:
class PButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.tt_enabled = False

    def event(self, event: QEvent):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Type.ToolTip and not self.tt_enabled:
            return True
        return super().event(event)

A Delegate that doesn't close the editor when pressing Return or Enter:
class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event: QEvent):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Type.KeyPress and event.key() in (0x01000004, 0x01000005):  # Return, Enter
            return False
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

Both examples work as intended but one uses event() and the other uses eventFilter(), and it doesn't work when you switch it around: use event() on the delegate and eventFilter() on the Pushbutton.
What's the difference?
I've read the docs on The Event System, eventFilter(), and event(), but did not find an answer there.

It's quite straightforward: event() is implemented and received by the object for which the event is intended, while eventFilter() is implemented on another object before that object's event() is called. In your second case, the event() of the editor (obj, unless you called installEventFilter() on something else) would not be called if you returned False. As the docs explain: "If one [event filter] stops processing (by returning true), the target and any later event filters do not get to see the event at all".

@musicamente, So I completely misunderstood eventfilters. As I understand it now, a filterobject is any QObject with a reimplemented eventFilter() method. And you can install such a filter on another QObject where it will intercept all events to that object. But now it's a complete mystery why the eventFilter() method on the Delegate does what it does. The delegate is not being installed as an eventfilter on anything. How does it prevent the return presses from being processed by the delegate itself?

Okay, I had not seen that eventFilter() is reimplemented on QStyledItemDelegate.

QAbstractItemView automatically installs the delegate as event filter of the item editor, including the editor created from the delegate itself or any widget set with setIndexWidget() (including implicit calls from higher level subclasses such as QTableWidget). By default, the delegate will always (possibly) filter any widget set for its related items. This is one of the cases for which an event filter is always installed automatically. Another case is QAbstractScrollArea, which installs itself as event filter for its scroll bars, and an internal object as filter for the viewport events.

@musicamente, Thanks, that explains a lot. And I feel a little less guilty for not understanding at first. This is not really a standard eventfilter situation. Could I have found that info in the docs somewhere about the view installing the delegate as eventfilter on the editor?

As far as I can remember, it's not specified anywhere (but I'm not completely sure). Yet, you can normally take it as implicit as soon as eventFilter() is overridden in the docs. If you want I can provide an answer that addresses all that, including source code references.

That won't be necessary. I ask question here to avoid having to read the qt source code.

Well, isn't that the point of answering? :-)
